# Change large image when we click on small image

Tags: javascript

There is a link give below open this and then click `table styles`. It shows all samples of tables when we click these small size table images then its shows in large image area.

http://www.pooltables.com/coventry-pool-table/?icid=in00007

I want to create some thing like this or find any similar script.

Comment: The link is broken, so I am voting to put the question on hold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the example you refer to is created in Flash, so to get similar fancy look and feel in javascript is not easy.

But it is quite easy to get similar functionality in javascript, but not with the fancy smooth transitions, and fancy look of the tooltips etc (it is possible, but requires a lot more...). A simple example of displaying image from click on thumbnails could be something like this:

```
<style>
  table#thumbnails{
    background-color:white;
  }
  table#thumbnails tr td img
  {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
function showImage(image){
  var mainImage = document.getElementById('mainImage');
  mainImage.src = image; 
}
function toggleThumbnails(){
  var thumbnails = document.getElementById('thumbnails');
  if(thumbnails.style.display == 'block'){
    thumbnails.style.display = 'none'; 
  } else {
    thumbnails.style.display = 'block'; 
  }
}
</script>
<input type="button" value="Show/hide thumbnail list" onclick="toggleThumbnails()" />
<table id="thumbnails" style="display:none;">
<tr>
 <td><img src="thumb1.png" title="Item 1" onclick="showImage('img1.png')" /></td>
 <td><img src="thumb2.png" title="Item 2" onclick="showImage('img2.png')" /></td>
 <td><img src="thumb3.png" title="Item 3" onclick="showImage('img3.png')" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td><img src="thumb4.png" title="Item 4" onclick="showImage('img4.png')" /></td>
 <td><img src="thumb5.png" title="Item 5" onclick="showImage('img5.png')" /></td>
 <td><img src="thumb6.png" title="Item 6" onclick="showImage('img6.png')" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td><img src="thumb7.png" title="Item 7" onclick="showImage('img7.png')" /></td>
 <td><img src="thumb8.png" title="Item 8" onclick="showImage('img8.png')" /></td>
 <td><img src="thumb9.png" title="Item 9" onclick="showImage('img9.png')" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
<div>
<img id="mainImage" src="img1.png" /> 
</div>
```

Comment: ya from this I can find something like this.Thanks

Comment: I edited and added a button to show/hide the thumbnail list. If you want it to appear as a popup, you only need to position it absolute and specify where on screen to put it. (<table id="thumbnails" style="display:none;position:absolute;top:10px;left:100px;">)

Answer (score 1):

You can try out something on [`this line`](http://jsfiddle.net/nQAJB/) .

In above example, I've changed src of img tag on `click` on image & on `mouseleave`, original image src is stored.

Comment: Thanks for reply .Please have a look of given link.then you better understand my requirement

Comment: In above URL, things are managed by flash/flex [not sure], to achieve this only in javascript, you also have to use image map. Ref. http://www.elated.com/articles/creating-image-maps/

Answer (score 0):

You'll never find a script that does exactly what you want if what you want is 'something like that'.

You might want to investigate javascript libraries such as jQuery, which make this kind of thing easy by enabling you to bind code to events.